# SSE2 intrinsics - comparing 2 __m128i's containing 4 int32's each to see how many are equal

Tags: count, comparison, sse, intrinsics, sse2

I'm diving in SSE2 intrinsics for the first time and I'm not sure how to do this.

I want to compare 4 int32's to 4 other int32's and count how many are equal.
So I read my first 4 int32's, set them in a __m128i, do the same for the second set, and use _mm_cmpeq_epi32 for the comparison.

This should result in a __m128i containing 4 int32's, each one either 0xffffffff or 0 depending on whether the ints were equal.

But I have no idea how to get from that resulting __m128i to a *count* specifying how many were actually equal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

The code as far as I'm piecing it together :

```
        int* source = blah;
        int* reference = otherblah;

        // Load the 4 source int32's (they are actually 4 int32s apart)
        __m128i first_4_int32s = _mm_set_epi32(*(source + 12), *(source + 8), *(source + 4), *(source));

        // Load the 4 source int32's (also actually 4 int32s apart)
        __m128i second_4_int32s = _mm_set_epi32(*(reference + 12), *(reference + 8), *(reference + 4), *(reference));

        // Compare the int32's
        __m128i result = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(first_4_int32s, second_4_int32s);

        // Perform magic here that counts whether 0, 1, 2, 3 or all 4 ints were equal ?!?!
```

Comment: Note that performing gathered loads like this is a recipe for poor performance - you might as well stick to scalar code if you can't use contiguous data.

Comment: Yeah, what you're doing here is probably a lot slower than doing it sequentially. So don't waste your time vectorizing it unless you can change your memory access pattern.

Comment: Are you doing this for just 4 values, or a whole bunch but just 4 at a time? Let me know and I'll be glad to write up a solution. That aside, here are a few points. If it really is just 4 values, consider a _mm_packs_epi32, then a _mm_packs_epi16, then a _mm_movemask_epi8, then a look-up table, but the scalar version is probably quicker. Regardless, you should NOT use _mm_set_epi32 like that, you should instead use _mm_load_ps or _mm_loadu_ps to load all 4 values together. Now, if you're going to do this for a whole bunch of 4-tuples you can just maintain 4 sums in an __m128i.

Comment: Then at the end you can sum the 4 components into one value. This can be don with shifts and horizontal adds or subtracting the individual components. Regardless, it's only done once at the end. While summing everything separately, you have two possible values after the compare. 0x00000000 or 0xFFFFFFFF. Keep in mind 0xFFFFFFFF is also `-1`. So, what you can do is subtract the value of the comparison from the current sum using _mm_sub_epi32. So, current minus 0 stays current. And current minus -1 becomes current plus 1 (subtracting the negative is adding the positive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can AND the compare result with a vector of ones to create a vector of zeros and ones. Then use a horizontal add operation to count the ones. Here are some possibilities.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "intrin.h"

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// non-SSE method (reference for result check)
static int method0 (__m128i value)
    {
    int index, total = 0;
    uint32_t *buffer = (void *) &value;

    for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        total += buffer [index] == 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return total;
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// horizontalAddBytes - return integer total of all 16 bytes in xmm argument
//
static int horizontalAddBytes (__m128i byteArray)
   {
   __m128i total;
   const __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128 ();

   total = _mm_sad_epu8 (byteArray, zero);
   return _mm_cvtsi128_si64 (_mm_add_epi32 (total, _mm_shuffle_epi32 (total, 0xAA)));
   }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// requires SSE2
static int method1 (__m128i value)
    {
    return horizontalAddBytes (_mm_srli_epi32 (value, 31));
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// requires SSE3
static int method2 (__m128i value)
    {
    __m128 count;
    const __m128 mask = _mm_set1_ps (1);
    count = _mm_and_ps (_mm_castsi128_ps (value), mask);
    count = _mm_hadd_ps (count, count);
    count = _mm_hadd_ps (count, count);
    return _mm_cvtss_si32 (count);
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// requires SSSE3
static int method3 (__m128i value)
    {
    __m128i count;
    count = _mm_srli_epi32 (value, 31);
    count = _mm_hadd_epi32 (count, count);
    count = _mm_hadd_epi32 (count, count);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (count);
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void createTestData (uint32_t *data, int mask)
    {
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        data [index * 4] = (mask & (1 << index)) != 0;
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void)
    {
    int index1, index2, expected, result1, result2, result3;
    uint32_t source [16];
    uint32_t reference [16];

    for (index1 = 0; index1 < 16; index1++)
        for (index2 = 0; index2 < 16; index2++)
            {
            __m128i first_4_int32s, second_4_int32s, result;
            createTestData (source, index1);
            createTestData (reference, index2);

            // Load the 4 source int32's (they are actually 4 int32s apart)
            first_4_int32s = _mm_set_epi32(*(source + 12), *(source + 8), *(source + 4), *(source));

            // Load the 4 source int32's (also actually 4 int32s apart)
            second_4_int32s = _mm_set_epi32(*(reference + 12), *(reference + 8), *(reference + 4), *(reference));

            // Compare the int32's
            result = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(first_4_int32s, second_4_int32s);

            expected = method0 (result);
            result1 = method1 (result);
            result2 = method2 (result);
            result3 = method3 (result);
            if (result1 != expected) printf ("method1, index %d,%d expected %d, actual %d\n", index1, index2, expected, result1);
            if (result2 != expected) printf ("method2, index %d,%d expected %d, actual %d\n", index1, index2, expected, result2);
            if (result3 != expected) printf ("method3, index %d,%d expected %d, actual %d\n", index1, index2, expected, result3);
            }

    return 0;
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No need to mask. Just do a `_mm_srl_epi32(value, 31)` to convert the 0xFFFFFFFF to 0x00000001.

Comment: @Raymond: Thanks, your suggestion is certainly simpler and more efficient. I updated the code.